# Why would Ext.util.DelayedTask retain a reference to components after they've been deleted, causing a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, extjs, memory-leaks, extjs4.2

I have several components that get destroyed when a dynamically created grid panel gets closed. When I look at a heap snapshot of the opening/closing process I can see that a large chunk of information from the panel is retained. The retaining tree says that the reference, at its source, comes from:

- Ext

  - *Some class*

    - superclass

      - focusTask

        - *Either:* cancel *or* delayed

          - Scope

From that point on the scope of this focusTask is the panel and its components. I've destroyed the panel, but its initialConfig still exists, and this in turn ends up keeping a huge amount the object around in memory. The class that causes this is changing, it's fairly inconsistent as far as I can tell and so far I've seen it fluctuate between these classes:

- ColorPalette
- FlashComponent
- Custom written classes

I can't see any common features between them that look like they would cause this leak, and none of them explicitly use delayed task, so I can only assume that this is something more fundamental with ExtJs. The fact that it's either the cancel or delay method, again with no real pattern or consistency also leads me to think that I'm accidently interupting something when I destroy these components. So is there some guideline as to when/what is safe to destroy something?

Comment: The question has some unavoidable complexity but I think you could rephrase it to make it clearer. Some sentences are ambiguous or not clear. Could you try to reproduce the problem with the minimum code needed on a fiddle?

Comment: Are there any parts in particular that you think are not clear, so I know what to elaborate more on?